# How to show a subfolder in a document library web part in SP 2013?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server

If I recall correctly, it seemed simpler on 2007 and 2010.

I'd like to get a subfolder show in a web part on a page for the user to see and update the contents of that particular folder without having to drill down to it. It's under one root folder with a score of others. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a metadata column to the folder and documents within it and then create a view with a filter on the new metadata. This will also help people see the power of metadata and views and help ween them off their reliance on folders.

Edit: Example - here is an example of how to do it. Note, this is a basic outline and there are variations on other settings you can choose which I will not mention here.

Go to your document library settings and add a new column, make it of type "single line of text". For this example, I've called it FilterBy. Now, whilst still in the doc library settings, click on "Column default value settings" under General Settings.

On the left you will see the list of folders in your library. Click on the one you with to filter on and then click on the column header to edit it. Enter a default value for this column.
[image]

A green cog should appear on the folder to show it has a default value applied. Now whenever you create or upload a document to the folder, it will have the default value applied to it.

Now you need to go and create a view. Set a filter on the view on your new column and default value. Now the magic bit, Expand the Folders option and check "Show all items without folders" and then save you view.

[image]

When you now select your view in the doc library, only the docs in that folder will be visible. If you set the view to the default view in your web part, that should hopefully give what you are after.

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks. Let me try that. Will it use any more resources to do that or is it insignificant?

Comment: On man I can't figure it out. It's asking for a filed name , etc I don't know how to use the term store management  tool yet.

Comment: Mike, you don't need to use the term store, apologies for not being clear enough in my answer. I was using the term Metadata just to refer to extra information tagged to a  document, it wasn't meant to mean Managed Metadata which is a specific type of metadata. I'll edit my answer to give a better example for you. It shouldn't use any extra resource of any significance.

Comment: Pardon the late reply. I hadn't had a chance to implement until yesterday. Roger, thank you SO MUCH for taking the time to teach me with your concise instructions. YOUR generosity is appreciated beyond words.